# RequireJS and Mustache (or any other engine): where to put templates

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mustache

I am using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) in a Javascript application. The content of the templates is inside some external files, which are loaded via the [text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text).

The only thing that slightly annoys me is the directory structure this imposes. All my scripts live inside a `js` directory, like this

```
index.html
js
  libs
    require.js
    text.js
    jquery.js
    ...
  controllers
    ...
  views
    ...
  ...
```

Hence I configure RequireJS with `baseUrl = 'js'`, to simplify module names. But this force me to have templates inside the `js` directory, otherwise they are not visible to the text plugin.

> Is there a way to configure RequireJS so that text files dependencies are looked elsewhere than the scripts directory?

(Of course I could avoid the text plugin and manually define AJAX requests to grab the files, but this is not the point of the question. If possible, I would like to use the existing tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an absolute path.  From the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html):

> However, if the dependency name has one of the following properties, it is treated as a regular file path, like something that was passed to a  tag:
>
> - Ends in ".js"
> - Starts with a "/"
> - Contains an URL protocol, like "http:" or "https:"

Answer (score 0):

I usually set up my baseUrl to . and script paths starting with js like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        "lodash": "js/ext/lodash/dist/lodash",
        "jquery": "js/ext/jquery/jquery",
        "domReady": "js/ext/requirejs-domready/domReady",
        "text": "js/ext/requirejs-text/text.js"
    }
});
```

Now I can keep templates in ./templates and reference them easily.